# I need to pick 11 th 12 th occurrence using correlation in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, correlation, load-testing

Option value = "Active" select = selected

This is the syntax of the regex

In request body

There are 12 values in regex. I have to extract all values and passing those value to respective request body

I need to pass
Account number: ${csv_accno}

Value1 : 12 th occurrence

Value2 : 11 th occurrence

Value3: 8 th occurrence

Value4: 7th occurrence

Value5: 4th occurrence

Value 6 : 5th occurrence

Value7 : 2nd occurrence

Value 8: 1st occurrence

PS: I have to pass all values in same request with respect to occurrence for all user accounts

Additional doubt: if dev team changed the html format it would be affect this script..

Could you please help to solve this issue...

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all [using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), consider going for [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor) instead
2. There is "Match No" setting which controls which "occurrence" will be stored into a JMeter Variable. If you put `-1` there JMeter will get all "occurrences" and store them into variables like:

   ```
   occurrence_1=value1
   occurrence_2=value2
   ...
   occurrence_matchNr=the number of "occurrences"
   ```

   You can see what variables does your Post-Processor generate using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination

   [image]

So you should be able to pass the values as:

- Value1: ${occurrence_12}
- Value2: ${occurrence_11}
- etc.

If response is changed the script will be "affected"

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can i use xpath extractor for correlation. When i write dynamic xpath script will affect in future..